# Recursive Model in Admin Add Page

Tags: django, recursion, django-models, django-admin

I have a model called `Category` which is recursive. The model goes like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='subcategory')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

my admin.py for `category` is:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from category.models import Category
from django import forms

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', "name", "sub_category", 'description']
    list_filter = ["name"]
    search_fields = ["name"]
    ordering = ('sub_category',)

    class Meta:
        model = Category

admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

When I want to add more categories to the database, I go to the admin section and do it however, suppose I need to distinguish which category is a part of its parent category how would I go about doing that? right now, I'm seeing:
[image]

which is not quite helpful, Is there a way to perhaps have the parent category next to the subcategory? like this format:

- [Java] Tutorials
- [Python] Tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was really stupid with this one, the answer was really simple, basically, I just had to edit the `__str__` method in the model...

```
def __str__(self):
    if self.sub_category != None:
        return '[{0}] {1}'.format(self.sub_category.name, self.name)
    return self.name
```

Comment: Just an advice: Better (always) use `self.sub_category is not None`.

Comment: what exactly is the difference between `!=` and `is not`. Is it just `!=` is based on value and is not based on Type?

Comment: This is an [excellent video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZ8bZPqtwU0) by Dan Bader to see the difference :). In a nutshell is what you're saying, type and not value.